# How to get the part of a string after the last occurrence of certain character?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, split, substring

I would like to have the substring after the last occurrence of a certin character.
Now I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44104657/postgresql-9-5-trying-to-split-a-string-into-two-fields-based-on-spaces/44105771#44105771) how to get the first, second or so parts, but I need only the last part.
The input data is a list of file directories:

```
c:\dir\subdir\subdir\file.txt
c:\dir\subdir\subdir\file2.dat
c:\dir\subdir\file3.png
c:\dir\subdir\subdir\subdir\file4.txt
```

Unfortunately this is the data I have to work it, otherwise I could list it using command prompt.
The problem is that the number of the directories are always changing.
My code based on the previous link is:

```
select (regexp_split_to_array(BTRIM(path),'\\'))[1] from myschema.mytable
```

So far I've tried some things in the brackets that came in to my mind. For example [end], [-1] etc.
Non of them are working. Is there a way to get the last part without rearranging my strings backwards, and getting the first part, then turning it back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `regexp_matches()`:

```
select (regexp_matches(path, '[^\\]+$'))[1]
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=345b2c0d4f26b62b19f49c36facecd33) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!
Could you please explain what does the ^ and the +$ part do?

Comment: The `^` says "anything but the characters in this character list".  The `+` says "1 or more characters".  And the `$` anchors the pattern to the end of the string.

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff! That was really helpful!
@Abra I know I should accept the anwer (which I just did), but it was answered so fast, the website said I have to wait 10 minutes to accept it.